# Enviar más de un correo en el mismo procedimiento

Tags: ruby-on-rails

¿cómo hago para que me envíe el primer correo? solo envía el último y quiero que envíe a los dos.

En los campos email y emailsoli, cada campo tiene un correo guardado.

```
class ReunionMailer < ApplicationMailer
   default from: 'notifications@example.com' 
   def autorizar_email(reunion)
      @reunion = reunion
      @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
      mail(to: @reunion.email , subject: 'Autorización de aprovador')
      mail(to: @reunion.emailsoli , subject: 'Autorización de aprovador')
   end
end
```

**Reunion.erb**

```
def  autorizar
  if self.auto = true 
    ReunionMailer.autorizar_email(Reunion.find(self.id)).deliver_now 

  end
end
```

Comment: Hola. Intenté clarificar un poco el título de tu pregunta en base a lo que me pareció entender que necesitas. Ten en cuenta que con el título se puede tener una breve descripción del problema que tienes. Mientras más puedas aclarar en este, mejor para quienes están buscando algo similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En caso que quieras enviar un solo correo en el cual se incluyan los dos destinatarios [la solución de jvilla8a](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/111684/42433) es la adecuada.

Si lo que buscas es enviar dos correos (uno para cada dirección) entonces debes llamar el método `autorizar_email` dos veces (una para cada correo); por ejemplo:

reunion_mailer.rb:

```
class ReunionMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com' 

  def autorizar_email(reunion, email)
     @reunion = reunion
     @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
     mail(to: email , subject: 'Autorización de aprovador')
  end
end
```

reunion.rb:

```
def  autorizar
  if auto
    reunion = Reunion.find(id)

    reunion.slice(:email, :emailsoli).values.each do |email|
      ReunionMailer.autorizar_email(reunion, email).deliver_now
    end 
  end
end
```

Podrás notar que he eliminado el uso de `self` ya que no es necesario utilizarlo cuando quieres obtener el valor de algún atributo (es necesario si lo que buscas es cambiar el valor).

Además cambié `auto = true` (que me imagino realmente buscabas utilizar `auto == true`) simplemente por `auto` (el cual ya devuelve algún valor `true` o `false`).

Comment: hola auto  es boolean  que cuando este en true envie los mensajes  a dos correos diferentes, gracias

Comment: @juangomez siendo así, la solución que propongo te debería funcionar tal como está.

Comment: puede ver por que no me esta.

Comment: @juangomez ¿Qué error te muestra?

Comment: ya es de otra pregunta yo se que ud  es un teso, la puedes mirar,gracias

Comment: es esta  si puede mirar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111931/habilitar-un-campo-para-un-rol-cancan-ruby-on-rails  gracias.

Comment: Hola @juangomez, no he utilizado _CanCan_ antes, por lo que en esta ocasión no podré ayudar con tu pregunta. :S

Comment: usted puede mirar  este problema que tiene un compañero gracias se lo agradesco.

Comment: hola  se envia dos veces

Comment: @juangomez ¿qué cambio hiciste?, ¿podrías abrir una nueva pregunta con el código que tienes ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Debes enviar un `array` con las direcciones de correo necesarias

```
def autorizar_email(reunion)
  @reunion = reunion
  @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
  @emails = [@reunion.email]
  @emails << @reunion.emailsoli
  mail(to: @emails, subject: 'Autorización de aprovador')
end
```